# Does TeX always insert the macro \par?

Tags: macros, tex-core, paragraphs

When the input processor encounters two characters with category code 5 in a row (in other words, a blank line), it inserts the `\par` macro.

When `\vbox{Abc.}` ends, TeX ends the current paragraph, but not by inserting the `\par` macro. It seems that TeX is inserting the `\par` primitive instead. Am I understanding correctly what TeX is doing in this case? What about other places where TeX inserts `\par`? When is it the macro `\par`, and when the primitive?

```
\catcode`@=11
\let\@@par\par
\def\par{\typeout{Macro!}\@@par}

Abc.

\vbox{Abc.\tracingall}
```

Comment: Best read on these things http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb14-3/tb40rycko.pdf

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are exactly 7 places in the TeX program where TeX executes the paragraph builder internally, i.e. turning a horizontal list (if there is one under construction) into a paragraph. This happens *not* by inserting a `\par` token into the input stream but by executing the procedure *end_graf* implemented in module §1096 in the TeX program.

This procedure does nothing if TeX is not in horizontal mode, more or less nothing if in horizontal mode but with an empty list (null paragraphs are ignored by TeX), and executes the procedure *line_break* otherwise (and that one does all the magic about adding parfillskip penalties, etc.).

The seven places are

- at the end of the internal vertical structures like the closing brace of a `\vbox` but also `\noalign` or `\vcenter` or an alignment cell
- when the primitive *par_end* is sensed (which is available on the macro level initially as the meaning of the token `\par`)
- immediately after an output routine (OR) has ended (thus any horizontal list started in the OR will not continue with material from the galley but form a paragraph by its own)

In none of these cases there is a `\par` token inserted (that might be subject to redefinitions); instead, the *end_graf* procedure is executed!

`\par` tokens are only inserted when in horizontal mode and primitives incompatible with horizontal mode (like `\vskip`, `\hrule`, ... the full list in is §1094 in the TeX code) are encountered. And of course in the tokenization process when TeX replaces two endline chars by `\par` (i.e., making empty lines equivalent to `\par`).

Comment: Hello Frank, as we say to new people ['Welcome to TeX.sx!'](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) :-) You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit (I decided internal TeX procedures also counted: I hope this makes sense).

Comment: Thank you Frank, this is a very complete answer. Going back to the Web code is indeed the right thing to do for this kind of questions.

Comment: I used italics for TeX procedures deliberately as that is how you find them in the documented TeX code as well and I wanted to distinguish better from macros or tokens but fine with me ;-)

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Italic doesn't work there because the underscore confuses the Markdown system. I'll try again using raw HTML!

Comment: Wait... I only count six places: `\vbox`, `\noalign`, `\vcenter`, alignment cell (only in `\halign`? or also in the display math version??), _par\_end_, OR. @Joseph: underscores can be escaped: `_par\_end_`. EDIT: ah, there is also `\insert`, and `\vtop`. Now I've got 8. :-/

Comment: @JosephWright How about adding `&nbsp;` at the end of the italics for italic correction;-) The joys of HTML!

Comment: @Bruno I said 7 places where end_graf procedure is used. I was not counting the detailed usages in each place. For example in §1094 a number of actual usages are covered. Anyway, it is not the usage of par_end (which is the primitive \par) to look for but end_graf. On the other hand I used the index of the printed program (so perhaps that is not correct ;-)

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Ok. I think §1094 only covers the case of the `\par` primitive (_hmode+par\_end_: ... _end\_graf_), and mentions the other cases, which are themselves treated elsewhere. I added to the [github issue](https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror/issues/62) a list of cases we'll need to care about in LaTeX3.

Comment: it also covers the cases where TeX inserts a \par token in response to seeing certain commands; the other places where end_graf is used are §1026 §1085 §1100 §1131 §1133 §1168

Comment: @FrankMittelbach: I am happy that such a great developer joined to tex stack exchange. You are welcome.

Answer (score 23):

According to *The TeXbook*, the rule for end-of-lines is as follows

> If TeX sees an end-of-line character (category 5), it throws away
>   any other information that might remain on the current line. Then if
>   TeX is in state *N* (new line), the end-of-line character is
>   converted to the control sequence token `\par` (end of
>   paragraph); if TeX is in state *M* (mid-line), the end-of-line
>   character is converted to a token for character 32 ( ) of
>   category 10 (space); and if TeX is in state *S* (skipping
>   blanks), the end-of-line character is simply dropped.

Here, it's important to note that the TeX inserts the `\par` token, and not the `\par` primitive. That means that `\par` has to be defined under all circumstances. Knuth illustrates this point when discussing commands which force horizontal mode:

> The appearance of a <*vertical command*> in restricted horizontal mode
>   is forbidden, but in regular horizontal mode it causes TeX to insert
>   the token `\par` into the input; after reading and expanding this
>   `\par` token, TeX will see the <*vertical command*> token again.
>   (The current meaning of the control sequence `\par` will be used;
>   `\par` might no longer stand for TeX's `\par` primitive.)

Now, what does not seem to be mentioned anywhere is what happens at the end of internal vertical mode. Clearly, the rules above do not allow for the insertion of a `\par` token as there are no end-of-line markers to deal with. (You do get a `\par` inserted if there is a blank line between the last material in the `\vbox` and the end of the box.)

Reading the trace output, there is no mention of the `\par` primitive at the end of the box, but the shipout does show

```
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
```

and of course there is clearly a paragraph built. So my conclusion is that the end of internal vertical mode implicitly inserts a `\par` primitive, and thus inserts the usual end-of-paragraph material and then runs the paragraph builder.

Comment: Very nice reply.  It can be improved if you define what \par token, \par primitive, restricted horizontal mode, regular horizontal mode, internal vertical mode are.  Of course, you can say, read the  book.

Comment: @Sony Given the nature of the question (low-level TeX), I've taken the approach that an answer can make certain assumptions about the knowledge of the reader. This is of course a tricky balance!

Comment: @JosephWright Is there any way to access the `\par` token?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I'm not sure I follow. The `\par` token is just `\par`, and may in principal have any definition. The `\par` primitive is saved by LaTeX as `\@@par`, or is accessible using `\pdfprimitive\par` with a recent pdfTeX or LuaTeX, or `\primitive\par` with a recent XeTeX.

Comment: Plain TeX, LaTeX and ConTeXt also makes a copy of the `\par` primitive as `\endgraf`

Comment: @JosephWright Sorry invalid question:)

Answer (score 3):

There is a reason why TeX puts the "original meaning" of `\par` at the end of a `\vbox`: consider the following silly input

```
\vbox{\let\par\empty a}
```

When TeX finds `}`, it backs it up, terminates horizontal mode by inserting the "original `\par`" and then rereads the `}` that closes the internal vertical mode.

We can emulate what would happen if TeX inserted the current meaning of `\par` before rereading the `}` by

```
\vbox{\let\par\empty a\vskip0pt}
```

because `\vskip` inserts a (current) `\par` and TeX rereads `\vskip`. The result is an infinite loop!

(Found in a [1993 discussion on `comp.text.tex`](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_frm/thread/d28c4fd0affe4929/1a3211a6ea3fb50d?lnk=gst).)

Comment: Same infinite loop happens before `\end` in horizontal mode, so I don't think this is much of a reason. I suspect the main reason is probably some implementation detail, and I agree with Frank Mittelbach that this may be a design mistake in TeX.

Comment: It may indeed be a design mistake: a "dead cycles" control should have been added for the automatically supplied `\par` tokens when a vertical command is sensed in horizontal mode.